# Why does this depth buffer setup not work

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I've been learning OpenGL (Cocoa) lately. And I've ran into a problem here. When I try to init the depth buffer, the compiler returns `GDB: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".` Here's the code:

```
-(id)init {
[super init];

[self initGL];

return self;
}

-(void)initGL {
glClearDepth( 1.0 );                     // Depth buffer setup
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );                // Enable depth testing
glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL );
}
-(void) drawRect: (NSRect)bounds {

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0f, 1.33333f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
glRotatef(10, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(10, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(10, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );              // Draw a triangle
glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );        // Set color to red
glVertex3f(  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f );     // Top of front
glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );        // Set color to green
glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f );     // Bottom left of front
glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );        // Set color to blue
glVertex3f(  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f );     // Bottom right of front

glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );        // Red
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );       // Top of right side
glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );        // Blue
glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f );      // Left of right side
glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );        // Green
glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f );     // Right of right side

glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );        // Red
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );       // Top of back side
glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );        // Green
glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f );     // Left of back side
glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );        // Blue
glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f );    // Right of back side

glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );        // Red
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );       // Top of left side
glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );        // Blue
glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f );    // Left of left side
glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );        // Green
glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f );     // Right of left side
glEnd();

glFlush();
}
```

If I remove the 3 lines of depth testing, the application opens seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a OpenGL context made current when initGL is called? Most easily this is achieved, by putting all the calls in `init` into the drawing function – **where they actually belong, because there's nothing about to initialize in OpenGL**.

Really guys, if you'd followed that simple advice to do everything related to drawing in the drawing function 80% of the worlds OpenGL problems would vanish.

BTW: You code will draw only a clipped cube, because you're still running on the identity modelview matrix, which means that some of your vertices come out before the near clipping plane. It's fine if that's to become a skybox though.